# Node.js - Mongoose - Check if a collection exists

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to insert some data using mongoose but the name of the collection is provided by the user at the moment of the insertion, so I first have to check if the collection exists.

The way I know how to check if a collection exists is by querying the `system.namespaces` collection. I can see 3 possible approaches to doing that.

1. Find a way to query `system.namespaces` using mongoose (maybe defining a schema that matches the one in the db).
2. Getting some underlying node-mongodb-native object from mongoose and performing the query manually. In any case, this is something I would like to learn how to do.
3. Using a separate instance of a node-mongodb-native (or some other driver) to perform the query

Number `3` is the least elegant and the one i'm trying to avoid, I don't want to load another instance of the driver nor create a new connection when mongoose already created one.

I'm going to try number `1` after writing this. I just checked `system.namespaces` and the schema looks quite simple

I'd still like to hear some opinions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Option 2 is probably the cleanest.  Assuming you have a Mongoose `Connection` object named `conn` that's been opened using `mongoose.createConnection`, you can access the native mongo `Db` object via `conn.db`.  From there you can call [`collectionNames`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#collectionnames) which should provide what you're looking for:

```
conn.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
    // names contains an array of objects that contain the collection names
});
```

You can also pass a collection name as a parameter to `collectionNames` to filter the results to just what you're looking for.

**Mongoose 4.x Update**

In the 2.x version of the MongoDB native driver that Mongoose 4.x uses, `collectionNames` has been replaced by [`listCollections`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Db.html#listCollections) which accepts a filter and returns a cursor so you would do this as:

```
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections({name: 'mycollectionname'})
    .next(function(err, collinfo) {
        if (collinfo) {
            // The collection exists
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me (mongoose version 5.1.1):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb'
// notice the mongoose.createConnection instead of mongoose.connect
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoURI);
conn.on('open', function () {
    conn.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collectionNames) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
        console.log(collectionNames);
        conn.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: I like that you referenced the constants (`mongoose`, `mongoURI`, `conn`), which I feel is missing from the accepted answer since yours is a real-world example and `mongoose.connection.db.listCollections` does not clearly define how to apply the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's  another option (with a little use of `express`, but I think it works fine without it) that worked for me. Suppose you imported a model. And, let's say `Blog` is the name of your model.

```
const app = express();
const Blog = require('./models/blog');

app.post('/example', (req, res) => {
  Blog.findOne({name: 'collectionname'})
  .then(result => {
    if(result) {
      //If it exists
    }
  })
})
```

'''
The `result` is either `null` or `object`.

Comment: It might be confusing to search for `'collectionname'` because that would just be the name of your Blog in this example and it would never have the collection name. But otherwise this is a helpful answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works fairly well in Mongoose 7+:

```
const findCollection = (collectionName) => {
  const collections = mongoose.connection.collections;
  let collectionFound = false;

  for (let collection in collections) {
    if (collection === collectionName) {
      collectionFound = true;
    }
  }

  return collectionFound;
};
```

and then you can use it easily in the following manner:

```
if (findCollection("mycollection")) {
  console.log("COLLECTION EXISTS!");
} else {
  console.log("collection doesn't exist :(")
}
```

Do note that `mongoose.connection.collections` only provides the collections available inside that specific MongoDB connection. It does not necessarily mean that you will be returned all the collections in the database. If you see some collections missing, then it just means that they were handled by other connections, such as being manually created via the MongoDB Compass.

Also see: [Connection.prototype.collections](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#Connection.prototype.collections)

Answer (score -8):

Find collection in collection's list

```
public function CollectionExists($collectionName)
    {
        $mongo = new Mongo();
        $collectionArr = $mongo->selectDB('yourrec')->listCollections();
        if (in_array($collectionName, $collectionArr)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Is Node.js, not PHP ;(