# How to check the existence of collection in mongodb through mongoosejs

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongoose

I use Mongodb through mongoosejs.
Ex: I want to check in my database have a collection called `Users` or not. So is there any function?, something likes `Users.exits()`.

In mongo-native have this function:

```
db.collectionNames("Users", function(err, items) {} //return the Users collection if it exits
```

Thanks!

Comment: Collections are created dynamically, so normally this isn't an issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js - Mongoose - Check if a collection exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444876/node-js-mongoose-check-if-a-collection-exists)

Comment: I get the problem is I want to query some documents in collection, but I do not know that collection was created or not by user

Comment: @WiredPrairie : It is not duplicated with your given which is mongo-native function. I am using mongoose

Comment: What? Your question is the same. There is not a way directly exposed in Mongoose -- so you resort to the driver underneath Mongoose. I still don't see why it matters if the collection was created (and why you're querying something that may not exist is a story for another time).