# check if mongodb DB exist at time of connection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am new to mongodb and mongoose. I used the below code from internet. I never created the database MEANSTACK which i am referring below. When saving the record it never complained that DB or collection does not exist like it used to happen in MYSQL. How do i make sure that DB or collection exists before doing any operation and its not created automatically.

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );

var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/MEANSTACK';

mongoose.connect(dbURI);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function () {
  console.log(chalk.green('Mongoose connected to ' + dbURI));
});

mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {
  console.log(chalk.red('Mongoose connection error: ' + err));
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
  console.log(chalk.red('Mongoose disconnected'));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js - Mongoose - Check if a collection exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13444876/node-js-mongoose-check-if-a-collection-exists)

Comment: That question is for collection checking. How about checking if DB exist or not in my example MEANSTACK

Answer (score 0):

Sry for writing my note as an answer. I can't write comments because my repo is below 50. When you run your server and it runs with no mistakes, that means your database var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/MEANSTACK' exists or at least your mongodb server is accessible. Otherwise you would get an error:

```
failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
```

And additionally mongoose creates a db if it doesn't exist on server run, so it do the check you need on server run like "out of the box"