# Check if collection exists before dropping in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When the collection doesn't exist when `drop()` is called, an error is thrown:

> ns not found

Currently I'm using something like

```
try {
    await MongooseModel.collection.drop();
} catch (err) {
    if (err.message !== 'ns not found') {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

which doesn't smell too good. It's not really clear why an error is thrown in the first place, I would expect that `drop()` will return `false` if it didn't exist, like it's done in Mongo console.

How can this be done when there is only a reference to Mongoose model, `MongooseModel`?

I don't have a reference to connection object in the place where I'm doing this, like is suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13445233/3731501).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually you do have the reference. You can `mongoose.connection` at any time after a connection is established and return the current connection.

You can also simply grab the [`db`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-db) from any model instance. So an approach you can use if you don't want to `try..catch` on errors when the collection does not exist, is to basically use the [`.listCollections()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#listCollections) method from the underlying driver in order to see if the collection you want to access actually exists in the namespace first:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/blank',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const testSchema = new Schema({},{ strict: false });

const ModelA = mongoose.model('ModelA', testSchema);
const ModelB = mongoose.model('ModelB', testSchema);

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);


    await ModelB.create({ a: 1 });


    for ( let model of [ModelA,ModelB] ) {

      let list = await model.db.db.listCollections({
        name: model.collection.name
      }).toArray()
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(list,undefined,2));

      if ( list.length !== 0 ) {
        await model.collection.drop();
      } else {
        console.log('collection %s does not exist',model.collection.name);
      }

    }


  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
```

Would demonstrate that the first attempted collection drop does not exist, without throwing an error:

```
Mongoose: modelbs.insert({ a: 1, _id: ObjectId("59aa9cfe581cca7afac55181"), __v: 0 })
collection modelas does not exist
Mongoose: modelbs.drop()
```

There are other things you can do such as use [`.collection()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Db.html#collection) from the underlying driver  with `{ strict: true }` to get a collection object first. But again this really only "throws an error". So whilst you would "know" before issuing the `.drop()` that the collection does not exist, it's still the same `try..catch` handling required.

So for no errors, check for the presence of the collection first. Provided nothing else is going to remove it of course. But you probably should always error handle just in case.

---

Personally I do find it simply cleaner to allow the exception to occur and then simply inspect the details to see that the exception being raised is what I expect:

```
for ( let model of [ModelA,ModelB] ) {
  try {
    await model.collection.drop();
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.code === 26) {
      console.log('namespace %s not found',model.collection.name)
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```

In this case `code: 26` for `"Namespace not found"`, which would be raised in this case or in the case using the native `.collection()` method with `{ strict: true }` as well. But using `.drop()` of the existing handle to the collection object is much shorter.

Point being that nothing requires you to actually log the exception, and "inspecting exceptions" ( i.e Expected duplicate key errors in bulk inserts ) is a common practice. Just test for the expected error code, and "if" something else is returned then you raise the exception at a higher level.

As stated earlier, whilst you "can" make the presumption that if you ask the database to list the collection by name and it's in the results then it exists, the safest course is to still catch any exception from the I/O in case there is some other modification in between the "query" and the "operation" to remove.

Comment: Thank you. `(await model.db.db.listCollections({ name: ... }).toArray()).length` works indeed but is ridiculously cumbersome for such basic and demanded task. try...catch doesn't look great too because the error should be asserted against its message (it's generic MongoError there). Wish there was a better way.

Comment: @estus My general case is to simply do the `.drop()` operation but expect that an exception could be raised for "namespace not found". On anything other than that return, then you "panic!". It's generally the cleanest and safest way. Added more detailed explanation on that.